# How to apply z-index on background-image?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code :

```
<div style="background-image: url(/Images/Main/BackMain.png); z-index: 2">
    <div style="background-image: url(/Images/Main/BackMain1.png); z-index: 1">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code doesn't show `BackMain.png` on top of `BackMain1.png` which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` alters the z position only of *positioned* elements. If an element is positioned then it will establish a new positioning context and its descendants will be positioned with respect to it.

Consequently, there is no way to set the `z-index` of an element so it appears in front of any of its descendants.

If you don't position the ancestor at all, and you set the descendant of `position: relative; z-index: -1`, then you can (in Chrome at least, I haven't tested it further) position the child behind the parent. This is likely to have unwanted side effects though.

Comment: Any alternative to achieve it with cross-browser support ?

Comment: Browser support for negative z-index should include pretty much every browser from the last 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have to change to html structure for this,

**html:-**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="object2"></div>
<div class="object1"></div>
</div>
```

**css:-**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}


.object1 {
    background-image: url("http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7124/8075023996_f61725fac4_n.jpg");
    height: 280px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.object2 {
    background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8054/8110021320_ebaa03c9b0_s.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Check what i have created:- http://jsfiddle.net/hJbHR/1/

Comment: `<div style="background-image: url(/Images/Main/BackMain.png); z-index: 2">` this is inside my master page so I can't edit it since all my pages need are inheriting from master page

Comment: I can apply anything other than reversing order these two. Can you edit your answer if you know the solution

Comment: Well your solution still didn't work.. I had to manually reverse url inside classes or reverse divs which this is what I can't do